# How to solve ngx-highlightjs StaticInjectorError with Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to use ngx-highlightjs following the steps described here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-highlightjs

Unfortunately, I did not manage to make it work. Nothing appears when I run the app and I I received the following error in the console:

```
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Highlight -> HighlightJS]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for HighlightJS!  
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:36417:27)  
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51335:24)  
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51261:16)  
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51111:20)  
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51335:24)  
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51261:16)  
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51111:20)  
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62298:29)  
    at NgModuleRef_.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63364:16)  
    at resolveDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63895:45)
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "ngx-highlightjs-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "ngx-highlightjs": "^4.1.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.24",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.24",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

**App.Module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HighlightModule, HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS } from 'ngx-highlightjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HighlightModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
    provide: HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS,
    useValue: {
      fullLibraryLoader: () => import('highlight.js'),
    }
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**App.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  response: HighlightResult;

  code = `function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Hello there!";
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "How are you?";
  }`
}
```

App.component.html

```
<pre><code [highlight]="code"></code></pre>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with angular 8.2.14

I solved it with downgrade to

- ngx-highlightjs@4.0.2
- highlight.js@9.18.3
- @types/highlight.js@9.12.0

You have to update you app.module provider to old syntax

```
{
  provide: HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS,
  useValue: {
    languages: {
      css: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/css'),
      html: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/xml'),
      js: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/javascript')
    }
  }
}
```